# How to check whether the Excel sheet is complete in OpenXML

Tags: excel, openxml

We know that an Excel file is actually xml files. But one problem is that how the xml format hands blank cell is not well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO1rU.jpg)

As you can see that in the second row, Column D is blank. So in the xml file, there is no corresponding node. But in the 9th row, there is Column D with its value.

Because the code will read the cells one by one, and convert them into datatable. This results in dislocation of the column values. How should we resovle this? Is there anyway to complete the entire excel sheet? Even if it is a blank cell, we still add it to the xml file with some special value? Thanks!

Comment: Every cell has a `r` attribute (reference) to indicate which cell it is, just use that. For example: `<x:c r="A2" t="s">`

Comment: Thanks for help. But some blank cell does not exist in xml file. In the picture you can see that there is no <x:c ...> node for D2 cell.

Comment: Yes but through the `r` attribute you do know which cells *do* exist so you can update the corresponding column. If there is no cell, you don't fill in the column